# Trying to create an object from django models after loading data with json, but I get 'TypeError: __init__() keywords must be strings'

Tags: django, json, unicode, models

I retrieved data from the API of a website and deserialized them using json.loads(some_data).
Json returns a dictionary that contains 'u' before each key and value like that:

```
data = {u'y_coordinate': u'1902125', u'case_number': u'HW301956', u'domestic': False}
```

Now I would like to instantiate an object from the Django models by doing:

```
obj = Model(**data)
```

However, I get 'TypeError: **init**() keywords must be strings'
So I was wondering if the problem comes from the 'u' in front of the keys and value, and if it is, how can I get rid of it in order to create the object?

I understand that I can write a function that would loop through the data and get rid of the 'u' whenever it encounter the character, but is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: This is weird, normally Django handles unicode strings internally. Does Ignacio's answer worked?

Comment: Thanks Ignacio for your answer. Unfortunately, the line of code you gave me does not work (I think it has to do with the syntax, because your code returns an invalid syntax error.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the dictionary, encoding the key whenever it is a `unicode`.

```
>>> {key.encode('utf8') if isinstance(key, unicode) else key:value for (key, value) in data.iteritems()}
{'y_coordinate': u'1902125', 'domestic': False, 'case_number': u'HW301956'}
```